# Is there a simple way to convert a socket to an SSLified socket in C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-xp, winsock2

In perl there are modules that you can pass a socket to and it'll return an SSL enabled socket.

Is there something similar to that for C++ that I can use as a drop in replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the literal way in which you ask: no, this is not possible. The existing APIs only support plain windows sockets, and provide no hooking for additional functionality. You will have to change readers and writers of the sockets as well.

Comment: Which is the easiest library to use? OpenSSL? I just need the basic functionality of encrypting. I don't need to verify certificate, etc.

Comment: Yes, OpenSSL makes it fairly straight-forward to maintain the illusion of a regular socket.

Comment: OpenSSL uses a very difference state-machine-based read/write model that most socket programmers are not confortable with when they use OpenSSL for the first time.  OpenSSL is very easy to get wrong because of this if you are not careful.  On Windows, the alternative is to use WinCrypt/SChannel instead.  Not only is it built into the OS, but you remain in complete control of the actual socket I/O, you simply pass inbound/outbound data to the API for processing.